# Who's "Isaac" which Eminem mentions in the end of almost each song of Music to be Murdered By Side B?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, rap

When listening to Em songs in `Side B, Music to be Murdered By` Eminem shouts "Isaac"(I don't know if that is the correct writing of this name). Anyone knows what this reference is?

Comment: Found a few links to Isaacs, like director Isaac Rentz, writer Isaac Jones and legend and [legendary-SP-guy](https://www.google.com/search?q=Isaac+hays+scientology) Isaac Hayes, but most weirdly: https://bindingofisaacrebirth.fandom.com/wiki/8_Inch_Nails but none noteworthy enough for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Why wouldn't it be the biblical Isaac, son of Abraham?  God asked Abraham to sacrifice him.  As he was a child Abraham had wished and prayed for for a long time, he was specifically cherished, and when God asked Abraham to sacrifice him, Abraham was less than enthused but went through with it and had Isaac bound on the altar and took to the knife before God stayed his hand, satisfied with the hold he had over Abraham.

That's sort of the traumatic stuff songs are made of.

Comment: Do you have some citation you can give to back this up, or is this your own interpretation?